# Error while accessing Database from Web Pages

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to access database from my Web Page in VS2013. It's giving me the error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

My Code:

```aspx
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Rohit");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Sample";
}
<html>
<body>
<h1>Small Bakery Products</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row.Id</td>
            <td>@row.Name</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

It is giving error on the `@foreach` line.

Answer (score 0):

The  `Database.Open(name`) method will connect to a database in two steps:

First, it searches the application's `App_Data` folder for a database that matches the name parameter without the file-name extension.

If no file is found, it looks for a "`connection string`" in the application's Web.config file.

(A connection string contains information about how to connect to a database. It can include a file path, or the name of an SQL database, with full user name and password)

This two-step search makes it possible to test the application with a local database, and run the application on a web host using a connection string.

Now consider these steps and try to Connect to your Database.

Comment: Error is on the line -   @foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)). SO i think there is no problem in connecting database

Comment: Please make sure that you have `.mdf` file in `AppCode` folder and `ConnectionString` in `Web.config`

Comment: I can find my Database in App_Data folder. But relative connection string is not there in web.config.

Comment: Added the connection string in Web.config. <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/> Now getting this error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: add connection string for your mdf file as follow: `<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionName"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: in Web.config there is already one connection string `<add name="StarterSite" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>`. So i have just written mine same as above `<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
`

Comment: Bro add `AttachDbFIleName` also

Comment: Getting error.  Keyword not supported: 'attachdbfilename'.

Comment: what to do? Please help

Comment: [have a look on this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/421835/Problem-in-Connection-String)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all - the database cannot be opened - which can happen due to a wrong connection string or network/db configuration. To troubleshoot, try to add a full connection string in the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add 
     name="Rohit" 
     connectionString= "server=myServer;database=myDatabase;uid=username;pwd=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and also verify if you can open your database when using Sql Server Management Studio (or other favorite sql tool).

Comment: Added the connection string in Web.config.      <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>                                Now getting this error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code"